# Incomplete CMD output capturing

Tags: c++, delphi, winapi, cmd, console

I tried capturing standard console output using command: `systeminfo.exe 1> output.txt`
but some text messages are still writed into console and they are not redirected to output.txt.
For example at program systeminfo.exe start in console appears:

> Loading information about CPU

but this text is not redirected to capturing output file output.txt.

Please how is possible capture this text?

I tried this command too: `systeminfo.exe 1> output.txt 2>&1`
which should redirect error console output to file, but result is that no additional information is displayed in cmd console and file output.txt cointains the same console output - without text, which program writed in first case in to console.

Is there some other console output stream which is hidden for me?

Comment: Those lines have a `CR` instead of a `CRLF`, which means, they get overwritten by the next line.

Comment: An application can write to the console buffer regardless of its standard i/o redirection, for instance with WriteConsole.

Comment: Is this really a Delphi or C++ question? Even winapi is a long stretch.